# Why use relations in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I understand the difference between embedded and referenced relationships in mongodb. By why do you need them in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB documentation has a section on this including a discussion on "why would I not want to embed this object?"

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Sometimes it's a question of the maintenance effort required to embed copies in each document, sometimes it's simply impossible to embed because of the limits on document sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really being asked ten times a day on IRC and various mailing lists. It's documented in depth on the MongoDB site (see above), various blog postings and talks and presentations. Basic research appreciated.

http://www.10gen.com/presentations

In addition: various SO postings deal with that:

[MongoDB Schema Design - New Collection or Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583086/mongodb-schema-design-new-collection-or-reference)

[Mongodb schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444911/mongodb-schema-design)

[MongoDB Schema Design - Many small documents or fewer large documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038703/mongodb-schema-design-many-small-documents-or-fewer-large-documents)

[mongodb schema design for blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224811/mongodb-schema-design-for-blogs)

Answer (score 1):

As well as the 10gen resources this is a really great intro to MongoDB, the little MongoDB book is an excellent & quick read along with the interactive guides.

http://mongly.com/